# Plotting a graph using cells containing two variables

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_vals = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05',
             '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10',
             '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12', '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14', '2022-01-15',
             '2022-01-16', '2022-01-17', '2022-01-18', '2022-01-19', '2022-01-20']
machine_vals = ['M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2',
                 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2', 'M-1', 'M-2']
shift_vals = ['Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night',
              'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night', 'Day', 'Night']
type_vals = [['Type A', 'Type B'], 'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type B',
             'Type A', 'Type B', ['Type A', 'Type B'], 'Type B', ['Type A', 'Type B'], 'Type A', 'Type B', ['Type A', 'Type B'],
             'Type A', 'Type B', 'Type A', 'Type B']
meter_vals = [[1000, 800], 1500, 900, 1700, 1200, 1300, 1600, 1400, 1300, 1100, [1400, 200], 1200, [1000, 700], 1500, 1600, [1300, 900], 1200, 1100, 1300, 1700]


data = {
    'Date': date_vals,
    'Machine': machine_vals,
    'Shift': shift_vals,
    'Type': type_vals,
    'Meter': meter_vals
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

Some cells in the Type and Meter columns have two values each. This means 1000 meters with Type A and 800 meters with Type B.

In this case, I have two questions:

First of all, is it a healthy way for a database to store two different variables in one cell in the column? Will it cause any problems in the later stages of the work? Do you have any advice for such situations?

The second of these is with the dataframe above,

- the dates on the bottom axis, on the other axis how many meters each machine makes to each date as Type A and Type B.
- the dates on the bottom axis, on the other axis how many meters each machine makes to each date in Day and Night.

The focus of my questions is how I should behave when there are two different values in a cell (for example: ['Type A', 'Type B'] and [1000, 800]). Thanks.

Comment: No it's not a good idea. Instead of `"Type": ["Type A", "Type B"], "Meter": [1000, 800]` Try change to `"Type A": 1, "Type B": 1, "Meter A": 1000, "Meter B": 800"`. And the `Meter` is nullable

Answer (score 2):

First, thank you for providing a reproducible example. Makes answering such questions so much easier.

So, first step would be to clean up your `df` a bit:

1. Make `Date` actual `Timestamp`s.
2. Explode the columns that have lists. It makes further processing easier.

```py
df2 = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).explode(['Type', 'Meter'])
>>> df2
         Date Machine  Shift    Type Meter
0  2022-01-01     M-1    Day  Type A  1000
0  2022-01-01     M-1    Day  Type B   800
1  2022-01-02     M-2  Night  Type B  1500
..        ...     ...    ...     ...   ...
17 2022-01-18     M-2  Night  Type B  1100
18 2022-01-19     M-1    Day  Type A  1300
19 2022-01-20     M-2  Night  Type B  1700

[24 rows x 5 columns]
```

Then, I presume you'd like to plot these measurements in various ways.

Here are some suggestions:

#### By type, each date has its own bar(s)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (5, 3)
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'

# each date with its own bar(s):
z = df2.pivot_table(values='Meter', index='Date', columns='Type', aggfunc=sum)
ax = z.plot.bar()
# matplotlib messes up categorical date formats
ax.set_xticklabels(z.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Aggregate by week

```py
zw = z.resample('W').sum()
ax = zw.plot.bar()
ax.set_xticklabels(zw.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### by shift (day or night), total meters, grouped by weeks

```py
z = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Date'), 'Shift'])['Meter'].sum().unstack('Shift')
ax = z.plot.bar()
ax.set_xticklabels(z.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Two plots: one for each shift

In each plot, show meter by types.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(5,5))
for ax, (label, sdf) in zip(axes, df2.groupby('Shift')):
    z = sdf.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='Date'), 'Type'])['Meter'].sum().unstack('Type')
    z.plot.bar(ax=ax)
    ax.set_xticklabels(z.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    ax.set_title(label)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]